# Messed up encoding in in Excel File by compiled maven program

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, maven, apache-poi

My maven program takes data from a file on the disk and converts that data into a **Excel XSSF Workbook** file using **Apache POI**.

When I run it in eclipse my Excel output looks like this:
[image: Desired output]

But when I execute "*clean install*" and run the compiled jar file it looks like this:
[image: Wrong output]

I have set my Eclipse file encodings to *UTF-8*

A snippet of my *pom.xml* looks like this:

```
...
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: "I have set my Eclipse file encodings to UTF-8" - I would have thought that accented characters would have to be Unicode (effectively UTF-32), but that would also require the conversion program to use Unicode strings, and not 8bit chars.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? All special german characters (ÄÖÜäöüß) are contained in the UTF-8 charset, why use UTF-32?

Comment: My assumption is that you are filtering your resources which causes such problem..

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox That entirely depends on your codepage.  If you look at this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples you will see that characters above 127 are not directly represented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem: In my **OpenCSV CSVReader class** I had a line of code like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file), delimiter);
```

but since my input files are encoded in UTF-8 **without BOM**, the CSVReader doesn't realise its encoding should the UTF-8. So I manually have to tell him like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), encoding), delimiter);
```